# Why can't I find Meta Stack Overflow in Communities searchbar?

Tags: support, communities-list

As you can see in the picture, [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) does not appear in the "MORE STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES" searchbar:

[image: MetaSO]

or

[image: SO Meta]

Is that a feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because MSO is no SE community by itself. It's a part of the SO community, which you can find using the "More Stack Exchange Communities"-searchbar.

Comment: True, worth to mention one can add meta sites to the "My Communities" list, i.e. they do appear when editing the list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, indeed, my memories were mixed up as I remembered finding Meta when editing "YOUR COMMUNITIES" list. You could add an answer for that, maybe...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [this correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291283/152859), I would like to add that you can add meta sites to the customizable "Your Communities" list:

> [image]